# NodeJS RegExp non-capturing groups not working like intended

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string `"14:00-18:00"` I would like to get the starting and ending time from it.

My code looks like this:

```
var startTime = hourRange.match(/([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})(?:\-)/);
var endTime = hourRange.match(/(?:\-)([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})/);
```

On something like Regex101 that returns 14:00 and 18:00 respectively. But in Javascript the first one returns `['14:00-', '14:00']` and the second one `['-18:00', '18:00']`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to specify the captured group.

Comment: I am specifying a capture group: `/([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})(?:\-)/` The first set of round brackets is a capturing group. `([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's not the problem. I'm specifying only one capture group and one non-capture group. The result should be `['14:00']` for startTime and `['18:00']` for endTime. But it's `['14:00-','14:00']` and `['-18:00','18:00']`. Even though `(?:\-)` is a non capture-group.

Comment: That's the expected output. The first item (index 0) is the entire match, the second item (and third, and fourth, etc) is the captured group. Also, the non-capturing groups in this case are unnecessary.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong: [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array whose first element is the whole match, then the capturing groups in order. BTW `-` and `:` aren't special here and you don't need the non capturing group: you could just use `(\d{2}:\d{2})-(\d{2}:\d{2})` and look at the first and second groups for `startTime` and `endTime`.

Comment: @Robin Thx for your answer but (\d{2}:\d{2})-(\d{2}:\d{2}) still returns "14:00-18:00" in addition to "14:00" and "18:00". I would like to get a result that just returns ['14:00','18:00']. Or is that impossible using Regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some confusion regarding the difference between a *match* and a *capture* so, to clarify: a regex matches one (and only one, without the `g` modifier) part of the string. Inside this match, it can capture multiple substring.

Your output is the expected behavior, as the [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function returns an array composed as follow:

- the first element is the entire match.
  `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})-` *matches* `14:00-`, so that's what the first item will be.
- the following items are the capturing groups, in order of apparition of their opening parenthesis inside the regex.
  `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})-` *captures* `14:00` in the first capturing group, so that's what the second item of the array will be.

If you use `(\d{2}:\d{2})-(\d{2}:\d{2})` on `14:00-18:00` the overall match (first item in the resulting array) is the entire string and the actual times are captured in groups 1 and 2. The start time and end time are the second and third elements of the result array.

So in the general sense, if you only care about the values of the capturing groups, you can just throw away the element of index `0` which will always be the overall match.

Hopefully that answers your question.